# OSMNX Is there a way to optimize a route both by length and travel-time?

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I want to calculate route optimizing both distance and travel-time. I can do it optimizing just one attribute.

Here is my code:

```
origin = (-33.4667,-70.7208)
destiny = (-33.367204, -70.506080) 



orig_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(graph, origin[1],origin[0])
target_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(graph, destiny[1],destiny[0])

route = ox.distance.shortest_path(graph, orig_node, target_node, weight='travel-time')

length = int(sum(ox.utils_graph.get_route_edge_attributes(graph, route, "length")))
time = int(sum(ox.utils_graph.get_route_edge_attributes(graph, route, "time")))

print('Distancia: ',length/1000,' km') # prints 9201.784
print('Tiempo: ',time/60,' min')
ox.folium.plot_route_folium(graph, route, route_map=None, popup_attribute=None, tiles='cartodbpositron', zoom=1, fit_bounds=True)
```

thanks!

Comment: How do you want to optimize by both? How does each attribute contribute to the penalty? You can minimize any edge attribute you want, you just need to calculate it and add it first.

Comment: I'm thinking something like a lineal optimization with 50% of timetravel and 50% of distance. In my example i have a 24 km and 28,9 min route with length optimization and 43 km and 29,7 min route with time-travel optimization, but in reality Waze suggest a shorter route than time-travel that combines the first part of "length" and the second part of "time-travel" route.

Comment: In which case, you merely need to compute a new edge attribute using your desired impedance function here, then minimize shortest paths by that new attribute.